# Use of ISNULL in a PIVOT Query in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm using a SQL Pivot to list the total value of sales per day per product and I'm having trouble replacing the NULL values of my rows.

The following table is an example of my data

```
    Date    | Product |  Amount  | Price  |
------------+---------+----------+--------+
2018-01-06  |  PRO 1  |    2     |   5    |
2018-01-06  |  PRO 2  |    3     |   6    |
2018-01-06  |  PRO 2  |    1     |   6    |
2018-01-06  |  PRO 3  |    4     |   18   |
2018-01-06  |  PRO 4  |    2     |   5    |
2018-01-06  |  PRO 5  |    3     |   6    |
2018-01-06  |  PRO 6  |    2     |   3    |
2018-01-06  |  PRO 6  |    7     |   3    |
2018-01-07  |  PRO 6  |    7     |   3    |
```

My query:

```
DECLARE @cols  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)='';
DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)='';

SELECT @cols = @cols + QUOTENAME([Product]) + ',' FROM (select distinct [Product] from #sales) as tmp
SELECT @cols = substring(@cols, 0, len(@cols)) --trim "," at end

set @query =
'SELECT * from (
    Select [Date], ([Amount]*[Price]) as [TOTAL], [Product] from #Sales group by Date, Product, Amount, Price
) src
pivot
(
    SUM([TOTAL]) for [Product] in (' + @cols + ')
) piv'

execute(@query)
```

My result:

```
   Date    | PRO 1  | PRO 2  | PRO 3  | PRO 4  | PRO 5  | PRO 6  |
-----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------|
2018-01-06 |   10   |   24   |   72   |   10   |   18   |   27   |
2018-01-07 |  NULL  |  NULL  |  NULL  |  NULL  |  NULL  |   21   |
```

How can I replace the NULL values with 0?
Doing `ISNULL(([Amount]*[Price]),0)` does not seem to do anything for it.

Comment: have you tried to use (ISNULL(Amount,0) * ISNULL(Price,0)) instead of ISNULL(([Amount]*[Price]),0)

Comment: Yes I have tried both of these and the `SUM(ISNULL(TOTAL, 0)) for ..` does not work because `ISNULL` is not a valid aggregate function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must replace `*` with a dynamic list of columns, and use `ISNULL` there. The code to generate this list could be something like that:

```
DECLARE @cols2  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)='[Date], ';
SELECT @cols2 = @cols2 + 'ISNULL(' + QUOTENAME([Product]) + ', 0) as ' + QUOTENAME([Product]) + ',' FROM (select distinct [Product] from #sales) as tmp
SELECT @cols2 = substring(@cols2, 0, len(@cols2)) --trim "," at end
```